# Explanation of the generalisation of multiset properties to a concatenation of a block

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis

I am trying to learn about SASAS cryptanalysis. I am reading the paper related to this where the authors use multisets are used within the cryptanalysis of this cipher. I did not understand the part where they generalized the multisets properties to a concatenation of a block. More specifically the last paragraph of the 4th page of this [paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2001/20450392.pdf).

To understand the context of the question you just need to study the 4th page of the paper.

Comment: This is an import question. None the less you should post any work you’ve attempted with regards to a solution. In addition if you’re interested in this area, look to the bijective mapping of theta() in SHA-3. The input set contains 25x 64 bit values, _or_ 64x 25 bit values. A distinction that _might_ be import when brute forcing a bijective mapping between inputs/outputs.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the cryptanalysis of the cipher.There are no other resources for analysis of this cipher.As multiset properties are used extensively in the cryptanalysis i need to understand them fully.But it is not that much clear in the paper.